# How many cookies are stored in my browser once I login to my gmail account?

Tags: cookies, gmail

I am learning cookies I read that whenever I login a cookie will be stored on my browser but I have seen there are more than 4 cookies stored in my browser?
Can anybody elaborate it how exactly works?

Thanks

Comment: how does this relate to JAVA?

Comment: I was writing servlet so i asked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cookie is essentially a name/value pair along with certain other attributes (like path, expires, etc.). A website can store multiple cookies on your computer if the website wishes to retain the information of multiple name/value pairs.

The cookies are sent as part of the HTTP response header from the web server and are invisible to your naked eye unless you inspect the the entire HTTP response rather than just the parsed HTML. You can view HTTP response headers using a tool such as the Firebug plug-in for Firefox (you will find them in the Net panel).